# Custom Address (Country/Territory): bad value for restricted picklist field

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, salesforce-flow

**Use Case**
I have a custom address field on a custom object and I want it to be prefilled with the Shipping of an Account that is a Lookup on the custom object. State and Country/Territory Picklists is configured to allow the state Niederlande and a few other states.
[image]

**My Approach**
In a record triggered flow (before create) I assign the values from Shipping Address of the Account to the custom address field on the custom object:
[image]

**My Problem**
When debugging, everything works fine. But when running in system with the flow activated I receive the following error message:

> Pickup Address (Country/Territory): bad value for restricted picklist
> field: Niederlande

**Trying with Apex**
I tried to set the value using Apex and retrieved the same error. Even the following lines failed:

```
List<PicklistEntry> picklistEntries = Agreement__c.Pickup_Address__CountryCode__s.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
    agreement.Pickup_Address__CountryCode__s = picklistEntries.get(0).getLabel();
    insert agreement;
```

**How can I assign the Shipping Address of the Account to the custom Address field on the Custom Object?**

Comment: Do you have record types enabled for this object? if so, check in the record type that the value is included for the picklis.

Comment: Since you answered your question I suggest you accept your own answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite easy, but somehow I missed it when testing. **I used the label of the picklist entry, but I should have used the value.**

To stay in the example mentioned in the question: 'Niederlande' is the label of the picklist entry for the custom address field country/territory. The value of the picklist entry is 'NL'.
The lines of Apex code are also wrong since it should be

```
List<PicklistEntry> picklistEntries = Agreement__c.Pickup_Address__CountryCode__s.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
agreement.Pickup_Address__CountryCode__s = picklistEntries.get(0).getValue();  // Note getValue() instead of getLabel()!
insert agreement;
```

**How I solved it in the end:**

1. Configure States and Country/Territory Picklists
2. Enable them also for Standard Address fields (this also includes mapping existing data)
3. Step back to the flow and assign CustomAddressField.CountryCode the value of ShippingAddress.CountryCode

Steps 1 and 2 are a huge amount of work if you have multiple countries with multiple states.